# Why spring batch cannot detect the used encoding within my input files

Tags: spring-batch

i thought spring batch can detect the used encoding with input files, i'm getting always `UTF-8` as default caractere with `flatItemeReader`

```
    // default encoding for input files
        public static final String DEFAULT_CHARSET = Charset.defaultCharset().name();
....
private String encoding = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
```

so what is the solution i should set the used encoding ? when defining my itemReader ? or is there an implicit way ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to spring batch official documentation ([6.6.2 FlatFileItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html)) it was mentioned that there are  some properties in `FlatFileItemReader` that allow me to specify how my data will be interpreted:

---

### Property   |  Type  |   Description

### encoding|String|Specifies what text encoding to use - default is "ISO-8859-1"

After reading this comment i understand that spring batch is not supposed to recognize my used encoding within my input files.